# Kendo date picker doesn't retain correct date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have a KendoGrid that contains 2 date fields. Both dates display with correct initial values passed by the Read transport. But, if the user edits either date then clicks "Update", the update transport receives the default date/time value of {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. all other data changed by the user is correct but the dates are all set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} instead of what was selected by the user.

ViewModel code:

```
public class CampaignViewModel
{       
    public int CampaignID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

View code:

```
    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: 
        {
            read:
                {
                    url: "/Campaign/ReadCampaigns/",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            create:
                {
                    url: "/Campaign/AddCampaign/",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            update: 
                {
                    url: "/Campaign/UpdateCampaign",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
        },
    batch: false,        
    schema:
    {
        model:
        {
            id: "CampaignID",
            fields:
            {
                id: { type: "number", editable: false },
                Name: { type: "string" },
                Descirption: { type: "string" },
                StartDate: { type: "date" },
                EndDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Controller code:

```
    public string ReadCampaigns()
    {
        This code seems to be working fine. all dates are passed to view correctly and the dates show correctly in the kendo date pickers.
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddCampaign(CampaignViewModel data)
    {
        all CampaignViewModel date fields are set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} for some reason
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateCampaign(CampaignViewModel data)
    {
        all CampaignViewModel date fields are set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} for some reason
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the link given below. It does have couple of solutions for the issue you are fixing. Please revert if the issue persists.

[Passing dates from Kendo UI to ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.falafel.com/passing-dates-kendo-ui-aspnet/)